# Unity: How to convert a float value to a 00:00 string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a timer that runs in the background and at the end of the level i want to show the leaderboard. i want to take this timer and convert it to 00:00 format 00 (Minutes) : 00 (Seconds) (i.e 01:40). How is that possible? I just need to do the calculations and the convertion when the Level ends.

This is what i have now. i start the timer normally

```
void Update()
{
    if(timerIsRunning)
    {
        mainGameTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

and now to add the timer in the 00:00 format i need to pass it as float but read it as string in the leaderboard

```
public void ShowResult()
{
    int min = Mathf.FloorToInt(mainGameTimer / 60);
    int sec = Mathf.FloorToInt(mainGameTimer % 60);

    users.Add(new User(userName, score , timeScore));
    users.Sort(delegate (User us1, User us2)
    { return us2.GetScore().CompareTo(us1.GetScore()); });
    int max = users.Count <= 10 ? users.Count : 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        //leaderListName[i].text = users[i].GetName() + "- " + users[i].GetScore() + "-" + Mathf.RoundToInt(users[i].GetTimeScore()) + "Sec";
        leaderListName[i].text = users[i].GetName();
        leaderListscore[i].text = users[i].GetScore().ToString();
        leaderListtime[i].text = users[i].GetTimeScore().ToString();
    }

}

class User
{
    string name;
    int score;
    float timeScore;

    public User(string _name, int _score , float _timeScore)
    {
        name = _name;
        score = _score;
        timeScore = _timeScore;
    }
    public string GetName() { return name; }
    public int GetScore() { return score; }
    public float GetTimeScore() { return timeScore; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing your own calculations you can use TimeSpan to convert to a time format. Input will need to be of type `double`:

```
double mainGameTimerd = (double)mainGameTimer;
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mainGameTimerd);
string displayTime = time.ToString('mm':'ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the piece of code I usually use

```cs
//Calculate the time in minutes and seconds.
int minutes = (int)levelDuration / 60;
int seconds = (int)levelDuration % 60;

//Update the duration text.
durationText.text = minutes.ToString() + ":" + ((seconds < 10) ? ("0") : ("")) + seconds.ToString();
```

Comment: You could use `string.Format` instead of joining strings with the `+` operator. Also, no need for your complicated conditional operator: Simply use `seconds.ToString("00")` and it will return you the string in the desired format.